# reqular exp to get last number from string

Tags: php, regex

Hi all
how can i get number(positive num) from string,if string syntax is the following:

> t_def_type_id_2
>  t_def_type_id_22
>  t_def_type_id_334

so,in the first string i want to get 1,and in the second i want to get 22 and in the third string i want to get 334 using preg_match_all or any other sutable php function

Answer (score 5):

You can use the regex

```
\d+$
```

with `preg_match`

Answer (score 2):

if there is only one number in the string, simply use `\d+`

Comment: That would match 0 or more numbers. More likely you want \d+

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/^\w+(\d+)$/U', $string, $match);
$value = (int) $match[1];
```

Comment: As with [@ian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473865/reqular-exp-to-get-last-number-from-string/5474000#5474000), this will only capture the last digit.  The `\w+` will initially gobble up the whole string, then it will back off one position at a time until the rest of the regex is satisfied.  Since `(\d+)` is only *required* to match one digit, that's all it gets.

Comment: Good point. Ungreedy matching should do the trick. I;ve updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
str_replace('t_def_type_id_','');
```

Answer (score 1):

**what about following code:**

^[\d]+(\d+)$

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace()`:

```
$defTypeID = preg_replace("/^(.*?)(\d+)$/", "$2", $defTypeIDString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "t_def_type_id_2
t_def_type_id_22
t_def_type_id_334"; 

preg_match_all("#t_def_type_id_([0-9]+)#is", $string, $matches);

$matches = $matches[1];
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 22
    [2] => 334
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the last thing in your string, then using a banal string function approach is possible and looks a bit compacter:

```
$num = ltrim(strrchr($string, "_"), "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^\w+(\d+)$
```

but I did not test

Answer (score 0):

Here's my alternative solution.

```
$number = array_pop(explode('_', $string));
```